# Global and Local Variable Confusion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, while-loop, scope

I'm doing some Khan Academy exercises related to binary search, and there is a variable scope issue (or at least I think that is the issue) that I don't understand.

The following code will work with the while loop:

```
var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    let min = 0;
    let max = array.length - 1;
    let guess;

    while (array[guess] !== targetValue){
      guess = min + max/2;
        if (array[guess] === targetValue){
            console.log("correct")
            return
        }

        else{
            console.log("nope");
            console.log("array num is " + array[guess]);
            console.log("target num is " + targetValue);
            return -1
        }
    };
};

var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
        41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

var result = doSearch(primes, 41);
```

while this

```
var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    let min = 0;
    let max = array.length - 1;
  let guess = min + max /2;
    

    console.log(array[guess] === targetValue);

    while (array[guess] !== targetValue){
        if (array[guess] === targetValue){
            console.log("correct")
            return
        }

        else{
            console.log("nope");
            console.log("array num is " + array[guess]);
            console.log("target num is " + targetValue);
            return -1
        }
    };
};

var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
        41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

var result = doSearch(primes, 41);
```

would return "true" for the console.log, but fail to return anything from the loop.

What I don't understand is why defining guess as min + max /2 in the while loop works, while defining it as what I think is a global scope variable outside the loop causes it to fail?

Comment: If `array[guess] === targetValue` is `true` then `array[guess] !== targetValue` is `false`, the body of the `while` loop will never be evaluated, and you reach the end of the body of `doSearch` without ever evaluating a `return` statement.

Comment: Be carefull with `min+max/2` I believe you mean `(min+max)/2`. ps. You should learn how to use JS step-by-step debugger in your browser developer console. Using it you'll be able to answer all your questions.